# Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: php, postgresql, apache2, arch-linux

I'm trying to setup PhpPgAdmin. But the service won't start.

I get the following output when `sudo systemctl status httpd.service`:

```
● httpd.service - Apache Web Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-04-14 12:05:14 CDT; 1s ago
    Process: 31293 ExecStart=/usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 31293 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 14 12:05:14 ardc-pc systemd[1]: Started Apache Web Server.
Apr 14 12:05:14 ardc-pc httpd[31293]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 10 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/phppgadmin.conf:
Apr 14 12:05:14 ardc-pc httpd[31293]: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Apr 14 12:05:14 ardc-pc systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 14 12:05:14 ardc-pc systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is my phppgadming.conf file:

```
Alias /phppgadmin "/usr/share/webapps/phppgadmin"
<Directory "/usr/share/webapps/phppgadmin">
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     AllowOverride All
     Options FollowSymlinks
     Require all granted

     # phppgadmin raises deprecated warnings that lead
     # to parsing errors in JS
     php_flag display_startup_errors off
     php_flag display_errors off
     php_flag html_errors off
</Directory>
```

Just like the wiki page of [PhpPgAdmin](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PhpPgAdmin) says it should be.

I'm running Arch Linux. I installed **php**, **apache HTTP Server** and everything worked, I saw my index page in **localhost**. But when I add the config file to **PhpPgAdmin** the server stop. What am I doing wrong?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.

As it says in the wiki page of [apache HTTP Server](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server) I needed to install the PHP extension. Following up the instructions everything work!.